# Skype notification script: get chat message recipient

Tags: linux, skype

I'm writing a notification script for Skype event notifications. (As far as I know, that feature is Linux-only; go to "Options", "Notifications", select an event and fill in "Execute the following script".)

For incoming chat messages, I can get all the information I need with:

```
my-script.sh "%sname" "%smessage"
```

That is, `%sname` is substituted with the name of the sender and `%smessage` with the message text.

But for outgoing chat messages, `%sname` contains *my* name. I want to get the recipient's name somehow, but my Google skills have failed me so far. Is there another variable for that? (Or any documentation from Skype of this feature?)

Comment: have you tried using %sskype instead of %sname?

Comment: Yes, it gives me my Skype username instead of my full name, but still nothing about the other person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because you're not sending a message to a particular user, but to a channel that you and the recipient are listening to.

Private skype chat with two participants is the same as 3+ participants, so there is no 'recipient' as such. Maybe there's a way to get the 'target chat name', but I've not been able to find a way to do it.